# Excel on Android

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, openxml

I am working with an web application which lets users downloads excel files using open xml documents/API. When I click on the link on my desktop (windows 7/office 13) it works fine and documents open up without any errors/popups. However, if I run the same workflow on my android phone the document downloads but excel complains that the document is corrupt when I try to open the document on my desktop as well as mobile. Any help?

Comment: Are you generating your Excel file in server ??

Comment: No, I am streaming the response directly.

Comment: Are you generating a .XLSX spreadsheet ?? And you use Open XML SDK >

Comment: Yes, I am using Open XML SDK and I do generate XLSX document

Comment: havr you tried downloading file in android and opening that file in Win 7 system ??

Comment: also have you tried open XML productivity tool ?

Comment: Yes even then I cannot open the file. I still says file contains corrupted data. I can't figure out why downloading a file on android corrupts the file.

Comment: just saying[you might already have done this] , try generating empty XLSX and download it in android [No DATA just create a basic XLSX] .. Other than that i'm clueless =-O